# Tomcat error: Element type "Connector" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: tomcat7, tomcat8

I have implied basic authentication on tomcat server and configured to have ssl encryption. Then my tomcat is not starting shows following error

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
>   Element type "Connector" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

any help ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when configuring a proxy connector in Jira after copying sample tag from their support page. Nothing wrong with the XML syntax according to my editor.

I solved it by going over the tag replacing all " with new " and all blanks with space. Looking at it in a hex editor to compare the difference between non-working and working config I see that the non-working one had had 20 09" (space tab) in the blank/space areas. The working one has only space.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `server.xml` file is syntactically incorrect. It is located in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf`. Simply check its XML syntax, there must be something wrong with the `<Connector>` element.

Try use an XML editor if you can't spot the mistake.

Comment: <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="500"
           scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/home/owner/Documents/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="entwine" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" />

Comment: I dont find any syntax error in server.xml .. I compared my server.xml file with another fresh server.xml from new tomcat ..

Comment: The xml snippet you posted is ok. Maybe there are more Connector elements in the file? Try to open the Server.xml in IE or Firefox, it will report if there are syntax errors.

Comment: Then you are maybe not looking at the same server.xml as Tomcat does.  Do you use $CATALINA_BASE, different from CATALINA_HOME?  The server.xml is read from CATALINA_BASE/conf .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I missed a **space between** 2 **attributes**.

Changing

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"SSLEnabled="true"
```

to

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
```

solved my problem.